# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (built-in components) or a class/function ( composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, routes, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I tried checking for wrong imports but it just looks fine, I have also verified the versions of react-router and react-router-redux. I am stuck one this one since two days, would really appreciate some help. 
https://github.com/shrutis18/stockApp
Do the following to run the app.

```
npm install 
npm start
```

Comment: Install the latest Node and then try `npm install` and `npm start`

Comment: I have 8.9.1 for node and 5.5.1 for npm , i dont think this is causing the problem, what does my version have to do with routing .

Comment: I am looking into code for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are exporting BrowserRouter from "react-router".

BrowserRouter is located in the "react-router-dom" package.

In src/routes.js